# Do the endomorphisms of a commutative monoid form a rig, i.e. a semiring?

Tags: ring-theory

According to wikipedia the answer is no, since a(b+c) does not in general distribute, and I am struggling to see why.

Edit: The wiki has been corrected! Thanks to all!

A specific counterexample would be great.

Failing a counterexample, at what step does the obvious proof attempt break down?

Sketch of the basic definitions.

A commutative monoid (M,+): Requires all axioms for an abelian group except inverses.

Rig (R,+,x): Requires all axioms for a (possibly noncommutative) ring with unity, except additive inverses.

Hom(M,M) has additive identity the zero map, and multiplicative identity ID, the respective operations are pointwise addition, and function composition.

Hom(M,M)  is comprised of all homomorphisms: f:M-->M

Is Hom(M,M) a rig? (i.e. a semiring?)

Is f(g+h)  = f(g) + f(h)?

Is (f+g)h = f(h) + g(h)?

Plugging in x to both sides...seems to work? What I am missing?

Added to question. Thanks to the comments, I suspect the answer is indeed yes after all.

Try to apply a proof that an abelian group has a (typically noncommutative) ring of endomorphisms.

If the starting data is merely a commutative monoid, the mentioned proof should create a rig.

Comment: Where on wikipedia does it say that?

Comment: I found it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring . It is the fourth entry in the section headed "Specific examples". It is claimed left distributivity does not necessarily hold. However, like the OP, I can't see why not.

Comment: I think wikipedia is just wrong. If $f,g, h$ are monoid endomorphisms of $M$ and $m\in M$, then $$ [f\cdot (g+h)](m)=f((g+h)(m))=f(g(m)+h(m))=f(g(m))+f(h(m))=[f\cdot g](m)+[f\cdot h](m)=[f\cdot g+f\cdot h](m),$$ where I used that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b\in M$. As this holds for all $m\in M$, we get $$f\cdot (g+h)=f\cdot g + f\cdot h.$$

Comment: It seems possible whoever wrote it was thinking of the classical example of the set of *all functions* on a monoid, which does fail distributivity on a side.

Comment: @rschwieb That makes a lot of sense. If you happen to make this an answer, I'd happily upvote